# AJAX and blockUI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show "wait" message with plugin http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/. ajax.php file is

```
<?php
sleep(2);
$arr = array('m' => 'OK');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

And jquery code is

```
function block() {
    $.blockUI();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
}
block();
$('#button').click(function() {block();});
```

How to show a "loading.."-message BEFORE of using ajax for getting "OK" and hide AFTER of using ajax? Now it shows and hides after using. I need also "async: false," in ajax json. Also that this block show two seconds.

Thanks

Comment: just one thing, json_encode return the json value, it doesnt echo it : echo json_encode($arr); Rest is OK and should work, the message is displayed before the call and hidden when it get response (maybe its just too fast to see it).

Answer (score 1):

In jquery ajax their is a property called 'beforeSend' use that like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(){
        showLoadingScreen();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.m);

    },
    complete: function(data){

         $.unblockUI();
    }
});

function showLoadingScreen()
{
    //include block.js for using this
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: 'Loading....',
        css: { 
            border: 'none',
            width: '300px', 
            height: '50px',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff'
        }       
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You should show him `complete()` as well since he wants to hide the message when the call is complete.

Comment: That is because your ajax is happening very fast on you local machine just remove the alert and check or deploy code to server it should work I am using same in my project

Comment: @Johan check my success function I am calling $.unblockUI so no need of complete :)

Comment: @Johan woops nice catch +1 :)

Comment: No helps from complete(). I updated this. I whant it shows block two seconds on refreshing and a button clicking.

Comment: @chandresh_cool complete will be called regardless on if the call ends up in `success` or `error`. So you can remove `$.unblockUI();` from `success`

Comment: I triet it. Problem is that, the block blockUI have effect AFTER that $.ajax complete in this case.